# Is there a legitimate method for saving/restoring installed games on Wii after the shop is shut down in 2019?

Tags: nintendo-wii, virtual-console, homebrew, wiiware

[Nintendo is planning on shutting down the Wii shop services in 2019](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27560/~/wii-shop-channel-discontinuation-q%26a).

After March 2018, you can't buy points anymore, and after January 2019, the channel itself will cease working. This also means that the only legitimate way to redownload stuff you've purchased will go away at the same time - effectively making the Wii a disc-only console.

As someone with multiple pages of purchased Wiiware and virtual console titles, this is concerning. If my console dies, my games die with it.

**I want some way to back all this stuff up in such a way that I can restore them if my console ever dies.** Unfortunately, it seems like all the ways to do this are at best unofficial, at worst go straight into piracy.

After 2019, the "unofficial" bit won't matter anymore, since the console won't have any way to talk to Nintendo's servers, and so there's no risk of negative consequences to my Nintendo account.

Nintendo's FAQ doesn't give any good answers here, and I fear they don't exist.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't take me into piracy territory? If I have to mod the console, that's fine, but I'd prefer some kind of application that could dump my games onto the SD card and modify them so they work with the new console.

<sub>Question note: This is not a duplicate of [this question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10092/is-there-any-way-to-transfer-wiiware-and-virtual-console-games-to-a-new-wii?rq=1) That was answered in 2010 and it is likely the situation has changed sometime in the intervening 8 years.</sub>

Comment: In the first drop down of the FAQs you linked, it states "Please note that content downloaded on the Wii Shop Channel can be transferred to a Wii U system using the Wii System Transfer Tool."  That to me sounds like a legitimate means, but it involves getting a new console.

Comment: Later on in the same FAQ, they state that the transfer tool is going away in the same timeframe.

Comment: I suppose then the only good option is to transfer everything before they discontinue it.  That, or we will have to wait and see until then if they come up with something else.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's actually possible, but are you wanting to backup files to an external source, such as a USB?

Comment: FWIW, here in 2022 the Wii Shop is still somewhat operational. I cannot buy or view any new games, but I can download all my past purchases and was even able to download an update for the Wii web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have an external storage medium with enough storage for the games, it's possible. You can keep the games on this medium, and then you can use the method [here](http://archive.is/GdoPq) to play them off of the medium.

> Put your SD card into your computer
>   You need to download the D2X CIOS INSTALLER
>   Extract it into the apps folder of your sd card.
>   Extract D2X-V10-BETA53-ALT.ZIP to your sd card or usb device into the folder /apps/d2x-cios-installer.
>   (I used D2X-V10-BETA52.ZIP there)
>   Put your SD card into your Wii, and turn it on
>   Open the Homebrew Channel and launch the D2X cIOS Installer
>   Your cursor will be on the cIOS D2X Version. Use the D-Pad to change it to the newest version (all the way to the right).
>   Move down, and change the IOS Base to 56
>   Move down again, and change the IOS to slot 249.
>   This version is only used by the Wii when checking updates. Set the version to maximum (65535).
>   You are now ready to install, so press A to continue. You will land on an overview with the available cIOS slots. The slot you just selected should be blinking. Several other slots may be highlighted in red.
>   Press A to start the installation.
>   Wait for the progress to complete.
>   Once it finishes, you will land on another IOS overview screen. Your freshly installed cIOS should be highlighted in a green color.
>   Press the A button to go back to the configuration screen.
>   Next, you want to configure the second cIOS. This time, use base 57, and slot 250.
>   Again, press A to install it and wait for the process to finish. Once everything is installed, press B to exit the application.

This method does assume you have a modded Wii (which is simple enough to do anyway) and you know how to use homebrew. If you do get stuck, you can always ask for help, just mention what you have tried and what the problem is.

---

If you didn't want to be reliant on homebrew, you can follow the method [here](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2806). (This only works when moving to the same console)

> Insert a compatible SD Card into the SD Card slot on the front of the Wii console.
>   Access the Wii Data Management screen.
>   Select "Channels."
>   Select the channel you wish to move, then select "Move."
>   Select "Yes" to move the channel to the SD card.

To do the reverse, you can follow [this](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2807) method.

> Insert a compatible SD Card into the SD Card slot on the front of the Wii console.
>   Access the Wii Data Management screen.
>   Select "Channels," then "SD Card."
>   Select the channel you wish to move, and then select "Move."
>   Select "Yes" to move the channel to the Wii console.

To me, this method is the easier of the two, and will be possible now. This method also is considered "official", so it wouldn't have any chance of getting your account banned.

Comment: welcome to Arqade. can you please quote the relevant section of the links you post. if they were to die no one will know what methods you are referring to

Comment: I have changed the answer to do as requested.

Comment: You may be able to copy them off the SD card as a second backup. The data will not work on other Wii's. But copies of it may work if you store a second backup on your computer. Just copy it back and you may be able to load it on your Wii.

Comment: Looks like Method 1 is the way to go! Method 2 won't work since the games are keyed to the system they're copied from. But this meets all the requirements - it's a softmod (but those are cake), it doesn't involve any piracy shenanigans like redownloading cracked games, and it's not super complicated.

Great find, and well done!

Comment: I didn't realise, I'll edit the answer to specify.

Comment: Is there even a concept of an "account" to be banned on the Wii? Especially with online game servers being taken down ages ago.